# Is adding folders to system path for reaching other modules is a dirty hack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have a commands.py module in directory that contain subdirectory with my script. I don't want copy it in every folder, that contain my scripts. Is that bad practice?

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")  # add previous folder for run script
sys.path.append(".")  # add current folder if I run script in folder, that contain commands.py
from commands import *
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: What is wrong with `from ..commands import *`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "somefile.py", line 14, in <module>from ..commands import *
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: Ah, ok, so you're not in a sub-folder of a package. Don't worry then. :)

Answer (score 2):

Current folder is always the first entry in `sys.path` (from Python's path-making perspective `'' == '.'`) so adding it is pointless in the second case.

The first case is more problematic - first of all, the current path should always be the first entry so if you insist on adding folders to `sys.path` at least insert them at index `1+`, or even better, append your path to the end of `sys.path` to ensure that all built-in and current-folder visible modules are accessible from their intended locations.

Finally, due to the fact that different parts are using `sys.path` as their search path in different ways, setting relative paths is really not a good idea. If you want to hardcode the parent path, use something like `os.path.realpath("..")`.

This is all under the assumption that there is no other way - I'd still urge you to rethink your design and avoid messing with the search path entirely.

Comment: If I launch script from parent directory, that contain commands.py it give ModuleNotFoundError without `sys.path.append(".") `

Comment: @EgorEgorov - can you add to your question an ascii tree of your folder structure, where are you running your scripts from and where your `commands.py` gets imported in. I think I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.